# Can not set defaultValue in datepicker antd

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd, default, react-hook-form

I am working on add users form. While adding, I may or may not select expiry date.

Now In edit scenario if Im editing a user who has no expiry date then in that case antd datepicker shows invalid date and when datepicker is openened it shows nan instead of any date.

[image]
[image]

If edit user value has expiry date then I want to show it in defaultValue else no I don't want to select defaultValue.

```
                                            <FormControl>
                                                <Controller
                                                {...register(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleExpiryDate`)}
                                                render={() => (
                                                    <DatePicker 
                                                    placeholder="Role Expiry Date"

                                                    defaultValue={id ? dayjs(getValues(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleExpiryDate`)) : dayjs("")}
                                                    disabled={getValues(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.neverExpireRole`)}
                                                    onChange={(value: dayjs.Dayjs | null, dateString: string) => {
                                                        setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleExpiryDate`, dateString);
                                                    }}
                                                    size="large"
                                                    disabledDate={d => !d || d.isBefore(new Date().toISOString())}
                                                    />
                                                )} 
                                                control={control}
                                                name={`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleExpiryDate`}/>
                                        </FormControl>
```

So what I was thinking is, in the defualtValue above I could put some logic that if id and role expiry date is present then convert that date in dayjs or else simply return false. But defaultValue is not accepting this -

```
defaultValue={false}
```

Not able to figure out how to achieve this. And I don't want to use 2 datepickers based on
conditional id and date

Any help is highly appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 1):

Your date has an invalid format. use a valid format for the date like
dayjs() or dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: Thanks for quick response. When I write dayjs() it selects today's date as default date. I don't want any date to be selected there.

Comment: then pass the 'null' keyword